# IBM Integration Toolkit (Eclipse) fails to create a new local integration node

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

When i click create new local node in eclipse IIB the setup hangs on the message:

> Begin running task [Waiting for integration node to start ] End
>
> running task [Waiting for integration node to start ]
>
> Begin running task [The integration server is being created ]

My OS is Mint-Linux. Are there any external logs?

Answer (score 0):

To investigate the node creation problem, I suggest you first to look into syslog.

You can tail /var/log/syslog and then make the creation of the node.

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep IIB
```

Example on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

```
Oct 19 15:04:15 nbu130-rudy IIB[3604]: IBM Integration Bus v100013 (IB9NODE.default) [Thread 3678] (Msg 1/1) BIP3132I: The HTTP Listener has started listening on port '7800' for 'http' connections.
```

If it still doesn't work then you should strace the IIB process. This is another story.